# How to evaluate limit with absolute value

Tags: calculus, limits

How to evaluate
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sqrt{1 - \cos^2x}}{x}$$

Should it be $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x}$$ or $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{|\sin x|}{x}$$

and if it's the latter, how to go on from there?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct with the second choice. Since the square root is written positive, the numerator should always be positive, so you need the absolute value. Because of the absolute value, you have that when you approach zero from the right, you get the normal limit of 1, but if you approach the limit from the left, the numerator will be positive and the denominator negative, so you will get a limit of -1. Since these limits are not equal, the original limit does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

You have
$$
\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{|\sin x|}{x}=\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\sin x}{x}=1
$$ and
$$
\lim_{x \to 0^-} \frac{|\sin x|}{x}=-\lim_{x \to 0^-} \frac{\sin x}{x}=-1
$$ the limit, as $x \to 0$, does not exist.